# Unsure where to place the Google Maps Autocomplete country restriction

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-maps-autocomplete

I'm working on the following code and I'm completely baffled as to where to place the Google Maps Autocomplete country restriction.

```
function addMarker(map, features){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(feature.latitude, feature.longitude),
                icon: feature.icon !== undefined ? feature.icon : undefined,
                map: map,
                title: feature.title !== undefined? feature.title : undefined,
                content: feature.content !== undefined? feature.content : undefined,
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                if(this.content){
                    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function isPluginApplied(domObj) {
        return getContextForElement(domObj) != undefined;
    }
    function getContextForElement(domObj) {
        return $(domObj).data("locationpicker");
    }
    function updateInputValues(inputBinding, gmapContext) {
        if (!inputBinding) return;
        var currentLocation = GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(gmapContext.marker.position);
        if (inputBinding.latitudeInput) {
            inputBinding.latitudeInput.val(currentLocation.latitude).change();
        }
        if (inputBinding.longitudeInput) {
            inputBinding.longitudeInput.val(currentLocation.longitude).change();
        }
        if (inputBinding.radiusInput) {
            inputBinding.radiusInput.val(gmapContext.radius).change();
        }
        if (inputBinding.locationNameInput) {
            inputBinding.locationNameInput.val(gmapContext.locationName).change();
        }
    }
    function setupInputListenersInput(inputBinding, gmapContext) {
        if (inputBinding) {
            if (inputBinding.radiusInput) {
                inputBinding.radiusInput.on("change", function(e) {
                    var radiusInputValue = $(this).val();
                    if (!e.originalEvent || isNaN(radiusInputValue)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    gmapContext.radius = radiusInputValue;
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, gmapContext.location, function(context) {
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                    });
                });
            }
            if (inputBinding.locationNameInput && gmapContext.settings.enableAutocomplete) {
                var blur = false;
                gmapContext.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputBinding.locationNameInput.get(0), gmapContext.settings.autocompleteOptions);
                google.maps.event.addListener(gmapContext.autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
                    blur = false;
                    var place = gmapContext.autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        gmapContext.settings.onlocationnotfound(place.name);
                        return;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, place.geometry.location, function(context) {
                        updateInputValues(inputBinding, context);
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                    });
                });
                if (gmapContext.settings.enableAutocompleteBlur) {
                    inputBinding.locationNameInput.on("change", function(e) {
                        if (!e.originalEvent) {
                            return;
                        }
                        blur = true;
                    });
                    inputBinding.locationNameInput.on("blur", function(e) {
                        if (!e.originalEvent) {
                            return;
                        }
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var address = $(inputBinding.locationNameInput).val();
                            if (address.length > 5 && blur) {
                                blur = false;
                                gmapContext.geodecoder.geocode({
                                    address: address
                                }, function(results, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results && results.length) {
                                        GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, results[0].geometry.location, function(context) {
                                            updateInputValues(inputBinding, context);
                                            context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }, 1e3);
                    });
                }
            }
            if (inputBinding.latitudeInput) {
                inputBinding.latitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
                    var latitudeInputValue = $(this).val();
                    if (!e.originalEvent || isNaN(latitudeInputValue)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeInputValue, gmapContext.location.lng()), function(context) {
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                        updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    });
                });
            }
            if (inputBinding.longitudeInput) {
                inputBinding.longitudeInput.on("change", function(e) {
                    var longitudeInputValue = $(this).val();
                    if (!e.originalEvent || isNaN(longitudeInputValue)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    GmUtility.setPosition(gmapContext, new google.maps.LatLng(gmapContext.location.lat(), longitudeInputValue), function(context) {
                        context.settings.onchanged.apply(gmapContext.domContainer, [ GmUtility.locationFromLatLng(context.location), context.radius, false ]);
                        updateInputValues(gmapContext.settings.inputBinding, gmapContext);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to limit the gmaps autocomplete to NZ, currently it's open. I've gone onto the old Google but all the results I'm getting don't seem to relate. Any assistance would be muchly appreciated :)

Comment: Does [this answer your question?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries)

Comment: In your `gmapContext.settings.autocompleteOptions`. Follow the link above for the syntax.